# app.put('url', middleware) doesn't run the middleware, Express NodeJs

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I have some middleware that validates all put and post requests to have proper parameters. My mocha tests fail for my update routes, and after debugging I've discerned its because my router doesn't go through my validation middleware for update requests, though it works fine for all posts and I mount the middleware for both at the same place and time, in the same way. Can anyone spot the issue? Below you'll find my test code, validation middleware, and where I mount routes.

In server.js:

```
//400 middleware

//this mounts the middleware succesfully
app.post('/:table', helper.validateParameters);

//this doesn't
app.put('/:table', helper.validateParameters);
```

In my test file:

```
it('should return a 400 error if no parameters are passed', (done) =>{

debugger;

//this runs through the validation middleware
  request(app)
  .post('/item/')
  .set('Authorization', testSuite.tokenHeader)
  .expect(400)
  .end(done);
});

...

it('should return a 400 error if no parameters are passed', (done) => {

debugger;

//this doesn't
  request(app)
  .put(testSuite.realItemUrl)
  .set("Authorization", testSuite.tokenHeader)
  .expect(400)
  .end(done);
});
```

In helper.js:

```
let validateParameters = (req, res, next) => {

  debugger;

  //The route handler never enters here when handling Item.put requests

  if (!checkProperties(req.params.table, req.body.params)) {
    //winston.log?
    return next(ErrorTypes.badRequest());
  }
  else {
    return next();
  }

 }

...

let checkProperties = (table, params) => {

  if (!params) {
    return false;
  }

  var requiredProperties = [];

  switch(table) {
    case 'item':
      requiredProperties = Object.keys(Item.schema.obj);
      break;
    case 'match':
      requiredProperties = Object.keys(Match.schema.obj);
      break;
    case 'user':
      requiredProperties = Object.keys(User.schema.obj);
      break;
  }

  return Object.keys(params).every( parameter => {
    return requiredProperties.includes(parameter);
  });
}
```

Comment: Did you check the value of `testSuite.realItemUrl`? What response are you getting for the PUT request?

Comment: To the one I'm currently debugging (no parameters sent in the update requests) I get back a "200 ok" response. This is probably because the query goes through with empty parameters and mongo responds with an "okay" because it just didn't change anything. So the operation goes through like a normal update whereas it should've been stopped at the middleware.

Comment: On a semi-related note, I think you meant to put `req.params.table && ` instead of `req.body.params && ` in your `validateParameters()` since `req.body.params` would already be truthy due to the `!req.body.params || `. I'm not sure that is the cause of the problem though. Is `req.body.params` set? If so, is `checkProperties()` to blame? How is your body parser middleware defined, is it applicable to PUT requests too?

Comment: req.body.params is not set in the example test, no. The validation middleware should fail the request in that first "if" statement in this case, but it goes through anyway. I'll update my question with my checkProperties code. I use the "body-parser" package to as my parsing middleware so it should be applicable to all requests

Comment: Your title says "X isn't happening", but you haven't tested specifically for X happening, you've only determined that X isn't giving you the result you want. First step should have been to place a debugger or log directly on the first line of the middleware, then following it until you find where it stops doing what you expect. Based on your comments, your title is false.

Comment: @KevinB I actually did test for x; I setup debugger statements in every test and the validation middleware, and found that whilst my router entered the "validateParameters" middleware for every "post" request, it didn't for every "put". I thus concluded the router wasn't using the middleware in the first place.

Comment: I had cleaned up my debugging code to help with clarity in my examples but I can edit my question to include it.

Comment: It's likely something farther up the chain is handling the request.

Comment: @KevinB I don't think thats it- I had debugger statements in my "updateItem" request handler and the router enters it for every "put" test. In other words, its my controllers and routers handling the requests. Hence me getting back a "200 ok" response for an empty, but still valid, update when the test passes no request parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! I originally mounted my validation middleware for put requests like this:

```
app.put("/:table", helper.validateParameters);
```

But the url I was using to test was "localhost:3000/match/5879234c3232" where everything after "match/" is the _id of my testMatch. As such my test url didn't pattern match with requests that went through the validation middleware, and the middleware was thus never hit. A simple fix adjusting the url I mounted my middleware on has everything working smooth as butter:

```
app.put("/:table/:id", helper.validateParameters);
```

Thanks to everyone who provided input.